# Capitalization in If/Else statement

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I have a question about capitals.

```
puts 'Answer "Yes"'
answer = gets.chomp
if answer == "Yes"
    puts "Great, you said Yes!!!"
else 
    puts "darn, how do I fix the capital issue?"
end
```

Here is my problem ... what if they write "yes" or "YES" it goes to the if/else statement.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String#downcase` to include all variants of `yes`:

```
if answer.downcase == "yes"
  #do some 
else 
 ...
end
```

This solution works in cases "Yes", "YeS" and so on. If you want to check only "yes" or "YES" you can use `include`:

```
if %w(YES yes).include?(answer) # %w(YES yes) same as ["YES", "yes"]
  ...
end
```

Comment: You probably meant `==`.

Comment: of course, already edited